# What is the best way get and hold property reference by name in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, .net-4.0

I want to know if there is a better way (than what I'm currently doing) to obtain and hold a reference to a property in another object using only the object and property string names.  Particularly, is there a better way to do this with the new dynamic functionality of .Net 4.0?

Here is what I have right now.

I have a "`PropertyReference<T>`" object that takes an object name and property name in the constructor.

An `Initialize()` method uses reflection to find the object and property and stores the property Getter as an `Action<T>` and the property Setter as an `Func<T>`.

When I want to actually call the property I do something like this:

```
int x = _propertyReference.Get();
```

or

```
_propertyReference.Set(2);
```

Here is my `PropertyReference<T>` code.  Please dissect and make suggestions for improvement.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public class PropertyReference<T> : IPropertyReference
    {
        public string ComponentName { get; set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public bool IsInitialized
        {
            get
            {
                return (_action != null && _func != null);
            }
        }

        Action<T> _action;
        Func<T> _func;

        public PropertyReference() { }

        public PropertyReference(string componentName, string propertyName)
        {
            ComponentName = componentName;
            PropertyName = propertyName;
        }

        public void Initialize(IEntity e)
        {            
            Object component = e.GetByName(ComponentName);
            if (component == null) return;

            Type t = e.GetByName(ComponentName).GetType();
            PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(PropertyName);

            _action = (T a) => pi.SetValue(component, a, null);
            _func = () => (T)pi.GetValue(component, null);
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _action = null;
            _func = null;

        }

        public void Set(T value)
        {
            _action.Invoke(value);
        }

        public T Get()
        {
            return _func();
        }

    }
}
```

Note: I can't use the "Emit" functionality as I need this code to work on the new Windows Phone 7 and that does not support Emit.

**UPDATE:**

Just did some speed tests after replacing:

```
_action = (T a) => pi.SetValue(component, a, null);
_func = () => (T)pi.GetValue(component, null);
```

With

```
_action = Action<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T>),component,pi.GetSetMethod());
_func = (Func<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T>), component, pi.GetGetMethod());
```

As suggested by dtb below.

Tested by making 100,000 calls to the Get() property.  Here are the results.

```
_func = () => (T)pi.GetValue(component, null)
```

took about 200ms

```
_func = (Func<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T>), component, pi.GetGetMethod());
```

took about 10ms

Huge difference.  Wasn't expecting that, but cool!

Still open to more improvements.

Comment: Are you even certain that `dynamic` will be available on Win7 Smartphones? It's a fairly sophisticated behavior that me not be supported.

Comment: There is no magic cure for Reflection, all of the proposed solutions use it.  Including *dynamic*.

Comment: No, I'm not sure.. I'll look into it.

Comment: Updated the original question with some performance results. See above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could obtain delegates directly representing the getter and setter method:

```
object component;
PropertyInfo pi;

_action = (Action<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T>),
                                             component,
                                             pi.GetSetMethod());

_func = (Func<T>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T>),
                                         component,
                                         pi.GetGetMethod());
```

Comment: This looks more concise then what I have. I'll try to incorporate this.  

Still looking for other ideas if anyone has them.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how often you're going to be calling it. If it isn't massive throughput, then fine - but note that the reflection-based `GetValue` / `SetValue` are pretty slow. You could cache the delegates, but another simple approach might be to look at [HyperDescriptor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx) - this uses the same API as `PropertyDescriptor` (so you again get `GetValue` / `SetValue`), but it uses dynamic methods underneath. The API then is something like:

```
PropertyDescriptor prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type)["PropertyName"];
```

or

```
PropertyDescriptor prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj)["PropertyName"];
```

then

```
object value = prop.GetValue(component);
prop.SetValue(component, newValue);
```

Comment: Fasterflect (http://fasterflect.codeplex.com) seems to be a more comprehensive library with a purpose similar to that of HyperDescriptor, although he did mention that Reflection.Emit was not an option (which would rule out both of these suggestions).

Comment: @Morten - I missed that caveat in the question - so yes, that rules them out.

Comment: Bummer, this sounded like a good solution.  I did look at Fasterflect and emailed the devs which is how I found out Emit does not work on the Windows Phone 7